# Filtering the value in Array with the value in another array

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I have two tables and I have USER_IDs that need to match one another.
When submitting the entire user list, I want to make a change if USER_IDs match.

I need to give information about which user can access which Scenario. I also need to indicate who does not have access, because access must be available through the panel.

I want this JSON...

```
[
  {
   user_id: 1,
   user_active: 1
  },
  {
   user_id: 16,
   user_active: 1
  },
  {
   user_id: 17,
   user_active: 0
  }
]
```

This is my Scenario_Users Table..

[image]

This is my Users table...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should select in such a way So that for every scenario you should have every user's permissions for the given scenario.

> You should be able to do this by taking a `join` of these tables. so that you get the users with permissions for a given scenario something like this:

```
SELECT s.user_id, u.user_active, s.scenario_id FROM Scenario_Users s INNER JOIN Users u on u.user_id = s.user_id
```

this will give you something like this :

```
[
    {
        "user_id":1,
        "user_active": 1,
        "scenario_id":3 
    },
    {
        "user_id":1,
        "user_active": 0,
        "scenario_id":1 
    }
]
```

if you want the users having access to a particular scenario you can query like this:

```
Select user_id, user_active from Scenario_Users WHERE scenario_id = 1
```

this will give you the list like this:

```
[
  {
   user_id: 1,
   user_active: 1
  },
  {
   user_id: 16,
   user_active: 1
  }
]
```

You should have a `user_active` column in the `Scenario_Users` table So that you can specify the access to a scenario for a particular user. But you are defining the `user_active` column in the Users table but it does not specify the scenario for which the user is active [when user_active = 1].

But According to your `Users` table and `Scenario_Users` Table, it is not clear that how you are defining the relation between user's Access to a particular scenario.

In your case, it seems like you are storing only the users in the `Scenario_Users` table of a user who has permission to a particular scenario, and your `User` table shows if a user is active or not.

So there seems no relation in tables for the scenario.

the JSON you want can be obtained by simply selecting data from your `Users` table

```
Select user_id, user_active from Users
```